# Unable to connect to live@edu through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to connect to live@edu using PowerShell with the following command.

```
$SessionNew = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://pod51002psh.outlook.com/powershell
```

Error:

> [pod51002psh.outlook.com] Connecting to remote server failed with the
> following error message : The WinRM client cannot  process the
> request. The destination computer returned an empty response to the
> request. For more information, see the  about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic.
> + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [],
> PSRemotingTransportException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

Can anyone suggest me what to do with this type of errors?

I am working with following System enviornment:
Win 7, default version of PowerShell & IIS feature enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Code working?

```
$Uri = "https://pod51002psh.outlook.com/powershell/"
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$SessionNew = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $Uri -Credential $Credentials -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $SessionNew
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `Import-PSSession` to work though, you will have to change local execution policy with:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```